# Google Chrome: How can I chrome to record a URL before it's redirected?

Tags: google-chrome

Say I am on http://example.com/. I fill out a form which is supposed to go `/add` (POST request) and then redirects to `/listing` page.

I want to find out details of the POST request. The issue is that as soon as it hits, it gets redirected and I can't find any trace of it in network tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the Google Dev Tools.
2. Go to the Network tab.
3. Checked the preserve log option.

That can help you log the POST request.

[image]